# rails nested attributes creating, but not updating and not deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people
  has_many :companies_people

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies_people, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class CompaniesPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :company_role
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class CompanyRole < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and I'm trying along with `Company` object to update it's `companies_people` associated objects. The issue I'm facing is that I can create new `companies_people` objects but not update or remove existing ones. And what is the most thrilling is that it's not another question about not permitted or missing `:id` and `:_destroy` params - I have those set up for sure, but still can't nor update nor delete an existing association.

Eg. this call which has a purpose of updating `company_role_id` from `1` to `2` is being totally ignored:

```
Company.first.update_attributes(companies_people_attributes: [{id: 1, person_id: 1, company_role_id: 2}])
```

ps. tested with Rails 4.2.4

Comment: If the problem is already solved why to ask the question?

Comment: @Deepak, to share my experience, which can save somebody several hours of his life. Any problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that it happens due to this association declaration:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :people
```

I had this relation defined as HABTM initially, but later as it often happens I needed to get access to the join table and created a corresponding model CompaniesPerson, but didn't update `:people` association to work via `has_many through`. And now I discovered that changing the above statement to

```
has_many :people, through: :companies_people
```

or just completely commenting it out fixes the issue with nested attributes not updating and not deleting. Wow, pretty unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem. The cause is rails doesn't know that your record is already exists.
You just need to add `:ID` in your parameters and it works.